# ACTION_CALL not calling phone number when triggered from receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

I am calling a number from a receiver which is sent using push notification. The code which I am using to call number is -

```
public class ExternalReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
            if (i != null) {
                String phone = extractPhoneNumber(i);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.ExternalReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />

                <category android:name="com.leadsquared.nextgen" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I've added `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission in the manifest.

This code works most of the time and call happens when app receives a notification. The problem here is the same code doesn't make Phone calls sometimes. In some devices, the failure chances are very high (more than 80%).

Has anyone faced the same issue or have a solution?

Comment: have you logged inside onReceiver() and checked if the receiver is triggered every time from the push notification?

Comment: @AshwaniKumar Yes, the receiver is trigerred

Comment: Perhaps the phone was sleeping when the push notification arrived. It calls your `BroadcastReceiver` while holding a wakelock, but as soon as the call to `onReceive()` completes, the wake lock is given up and the phone goes back to sleep before it can make the phone call. You might try to hold a wake lock and wait for the call to complete.

Comment: @DavidWasser Phone was awake when push notification arrived. All the code inside onReceive was called but the call didn't happen. Sleep is certainly not the reason